# OnClick bypasses form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, jquery-events

I have a form which is  made like this:

```
<form id= 'lol' name = 'whyyyyy'>
<input name='dumbo'>
<input name='idiot'>

<input type='submit' value='I have no idea why its like this' onclick='document.lol.submit()'>
</form>
```

Now, I want to prevent the actual sending of the form, but so far all attempts failed.

My current code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form[name="whyyyyy"]').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
        alert(1);
        return false;
     });
})
```

but the inline submit command bypasses as it seems the jQuery function.

Can someone shred light into it?

EDIT:

1. The form CANNOT be changed, I don't have permission to change.
2. the on click code should trigger the submit function, it some complex validation wall of code in it. So I have to cache the submit action that it triggers, but I can't do that at moment.
3. the submit function should be triggered on send but it does not get triggered.

Here is an example of the code in jfiddle. As you can see it gets past by jQuery...

http://jsfiddle.net/StCPp/4/

Comment: Whats up with the single quotes, you should use double quotes to wrap  attribute values

Comment: Is the submit handler executed and the alert shown?

Comment: No that is the problem, the executuion handler gets ignored.

Comment: As per my testing, the inline function actually **doesn't** work and your script **can** successfully prevents the form being submitted. http://jsfiddle.net/akGY3/1/

Comment: So get permission to change it. The constraints you're working under are ludicrous!

Comment: Did you try `event.stopPropagation()` in your jQuery call?

Comment: Also, you can use JavaScript to change the type of the button..

Comment: No the event.stopPropagation() dous not help to here is the proof.
http://jsfiddle.net/StCPp/5/

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need a submit button, why don't you use a regular button instead

```
<input type="button" />
```

Comment: it is not my form, i have to implement a workround and cant change the legacy code.. Q___Q

Comment: And it seems you missed the point, the point is in the on click event which bypasses the jquery handler

Comment: becouse it is not in my editing scope, dont have permision to change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='button' value='i have no idea why he done it like this' onclick='document.getElementById('lol').submit()'>
```

Comment: As pointed out in reply to @RiccoE i cant change that part...  only the document ready part

Answer (score 0):

Just use a normal button instead of a submit.

If you want to bypass a submit button you can make the class of the button cancel.

```
 <input type='submit' class='cancel' value='i have no idea why he done it like this' onclick='document.lol.submit()'>
```

Comment: Cant edit the form it self, need to implement a solution for it from the document ready function.

Comment: Then add the class cancel to the submit button in the document ready function. addClass('cancel')

Comment: What would that accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

In your add-on JavaScript, remove the inline onclick event and replace it with whatever you desire. Problem solved.

You could also completely remove his button and replace it with one of your choice.

Comment: Sorry cant do that, becouse i can not directly edit the form, and the form has some big wall of code in th on click function. Which on end trigers a form submit, which ignores the jquery, im guesing becouse it gets trigerd on such a low level.

Comment: Can you save off the click function and call it after you've done the new stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `document.lol.submit` function. This way, you can do whatever you want.

```
// Magic line
delete document.lol.submit;

// Or
$('form[name="whyyyyy"] input[type=submit]').attr('onclick', '');

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form[name="whyyyyy"]').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(1);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: That wont work, tried it just now.
i am guessing because it is sent in a in line code which represents a new instance of js. And the delete dous not get trough to it or no idea what.

Comment: @Sangoku did you try both?

Comment: I cant use the remove click function, becouse it has some giant legacy code in it.

Comment: @Sangoku then remove it, store it somewhere, prevent the form, and re-run the function you have stored. If the submit happens in the function, you *have* to change it though.

Comment: I found the solution, not jqrey but still usable.

Comment: I just bound the submit function directly via javascript... it seems like this is a possible jqery bug.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the onclick

```
$('input[type=submit]').attr('onclick','')
```

Then add the click event to function ready

```
 $('input[type=submit]').on('click',function(){
      //do your event
});
```

Comment: You should use the correct selector to get only the submit button `$('input[type=submit]')`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if I got this right you could remove the inline event handler `onclick` and add your custom handler (where you do the validation and all necessary steps):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var $submit_button = $('input[type=submit]');

   $submit_button.removeAttr('onclick');

   $submit_button.click(function() {
     //TODO: implement your custom handler
     //execute validation etc.
   });

});
```

Comment: Sadly no. the on click function is  generated by a monster of a file like 2k lines which are over 10 years old... But i menaged to bind the end result submit action to a function. And may i ask why the downvote?

Comment: Sure, please check the language in your answer. Also, next time, if you have specific constraints please make them clear immediately in the question and not after receiving many answers.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't necessarily required to use jquery to implement this. You could use standard javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    document.whyyyyy.submit = function(e){

        alert(1);
        return false; 
};
});
```

This example works, but you might be hitting a jquery bug.